# Changing an Archive.org link with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have a bunch of links to archive.org folders which contain movie files inside. For example:

https://archive.org/details/dmbb44435

The movie filename is always the same as the folder name. So in the example above the movie is dmbb44435.mp4. The full url is thus:

https://archive.org/download/dmbb44435/dmbb44435.mp4

How do I use notepad++ to add the filename onto the end of the URL using find+replace? Thanks

Comment: In Replace window: "Find what": ^https:\/\/archive\.org\/details\/(.+)$ "Replace with": https: // archive . org / download / \1 / \1 . mp4 (without spaces) Check Search Mode -> Regular expression

Answer (score 2):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `https://archive.org/\Kdetails(/.+?(?!\.mp4))`
- Replace with: `download$1$1.mp4`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
https://archive.org/    : literally
\K                      : forget all we have seen until this position
details                 : literally
(                       : start group 1
  /                     : a slash
  .+?                   : 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
  (?!\.mp4)             : negative lookahead, to make sure we don't have ".mp4" after
)                       : end group 1
```

**Replacement:**

```
download        : literally
$1              : content of group 1
$1              : content of group 1
.mp4            : literally
```

**Result for given example:**

```
https://archive.org/download/dmbb44435/dmbb44435.mp4
```